# Python - Login to Website

Tags: python, python-2.7, post

I know that there are several posts on this subject and I believe I have read a significant amount of them, however I still can't login to this website.

Below is my inspection of the login page:

```
<form id="login" name="login" method="POST" action="/signin">
        <div id="login_username">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="textfield" id="email" name="email" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="login_password">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input class="textfield" id="password" name="password" 
type="password" autocomplete="off" value="">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hash" name="hash" value="">
        <div id="login_submit">
            <a id="forgot_password_link">Forgot Password?</a>
            <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Sign In">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Below is my code:

```
username = 'XXXXX@gmail.com'
password = 'XXXX'
hash = ''

data = {'password':password, 'email':username,'hash':hash}

login_url = "https://carmel.orangetheoryfitness.com/login"

s = requests.session()
result = s.post(login_url, data=data, headers = dict(referer=login_url))
scrape_url = 'https://carmel.orangetheoryfitness.com/apps/otf/classes/view?id=16297&loc=0'
result = s.get(url=scrape_url)
```

From here I go on to search the html document but I'm not finding what I want as I am sent back to the login page when getting the scrape_url.  I have verified this by inspecting the resulting html document.

Things I have considered:

-Almost all blog posts or SO responses indicate that usually a CSRF token is required. I have searched the login page and can't find a CSRF token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has an `action="/signin"` attribute so you need to post to `https://carmel.orangetheoryfitness.com/signin` instead.

```
result = s.post('https://carmel.orangetheoryfitness.com/signin', data=data, headers = dict(referer=login_url))
```